# PHP PUT request with json request body not working correctly

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, put

**EDIT: For some reason, this server is expecting a header `'Accept: application/json'` .  When I added that, it worked fine.**

I have tried several different ways to do a PUT request with a JSON request body. I always get an error saying that they didn't receive the data.  I don't know if it's my code or their server.  This is what I have now.  Also, I have tried every combination of `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');` and `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` and nothing works.

However I get an error sending the exact same data using the following PHP

```php
$curl = curl_init();

$data = json_encode($data_array);

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));

$headers[]= 'Authorization: Basic '.AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN;


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're meant to have two `Authorization` headers? If so, you should have a space between `Authorization:` and the value; your first one is missing that space

Comment: @Phil  That was a copy/paste error. Should only be the one above.

Comment: Just saw your update. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

Use the [curl_errno](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php)
 in order to get the specific error as follow:

```php
$error_msg = NULL;
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
if ($error_msg !== NULL) {
    print_r($error_msg);
}
```